# How can I avoid running singular expressions against arrays in activerecord and rails 3?

Tags: activerecord, arel, rails-3.1

I am sorry if I am asking the question poorly. I have a Rails 3.1 app with models (simplified) like so:

```
class Employee < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many    :merged_children, :class_name => 'Employee', :foreign_key => "merge_parent_id"
  has_many    :timesheets

  def total_time 
    merged_children.timesheets.in_range(range).hours_minutes.sum 
  end
end

class Timesheet < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :employee

  def in_range(range)
    # filter records based on transaction_date in range 
  end

  def hours_minutes
    (hours + minutes/60.0).to_f
  end
end
```

Note: The in_range method acts as a scope, essentially, and hours_minutes is a calculation. hours_minutes is valid for each timesheet record in the resulting dataset, and then total_time should sum those values and return the amount.

The "total_time" method is not working because employee.merged_children returns an array and timesheets is meant to run against a single Employee object.

Is there any way to structure the "total_time" so that it still sends one query to the db? It seems inelegant to iterate over the merged_children array, issuing a query for each. Not sure if a direct call to an Arel table would help or hurt, but I am open to ideas.

If we get it right, the resulting SQL should effectively look something like:

```
SELECT sum(hours + minutes/60.0)
FROM employees e1 join employees e2 on e1.id = e2.merge_parent_id join timesheets t on t.employee_id = e2.id
WHERE e1.id = [@employee.id] and t.transaction_date BETWEEN [@range.begin] and [@range.end]
```

Thanks so much!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The easiest thing here might be to add

```
has_many :children_timesheets, :through => :merged_children, :source => :timesheets
```

To your employee model,

Then (assuming in_range is actually a scope, or a class method that does a find)

```
children_timesheets.in_range(...)
```

Should be the collection of timesheets you're interested in and you can do something like

```
children_timesheets.in_range(...).collect(&:hours_minutes).sum
```

Comment: This is perfect. We ended up using this precisely. Thanks so much.

Answer (score 0):

Untested with actual data.

```
  range = ((1.day.ago)...(2.days.ago))
  merge_parent = Employee.find(some_id)

  Timesheet.where(:transaction_date => range)
     .joins(:employee).where(:employees => {:merge_parent_id => merge_parent.id})
     .sum('hours*60 + minutes')

   (0.3ms)  SELECT SUM(hours*60 + minutes) AS sum_id FROM "timesheets" INNER JOIN "employees" ON "employees"."id" = "timesheets"."employee_id" WHERE "employees"."merge_parent_id" = 1 AND ("timesheets"."created_at" >= '2011-12-13 03:04:35.085416' AND "timesheets"."created_at" < '2011-12-12 03:04:
```

Returns "0" for me.  So hopefully it will return something nicer for you

Comment: This is a fantastic start, and I am currently playing around with it to get where we need to be, but the key challenge is to have the total_time method exist in the Employee class in this case. The object-oriented play is that an employee should "know" what his/her total time is rather than having the query have to originate from the Timesheet class. Any thoughts? (and thanks!)